# Unwatching an agent without resetting perspective

Tags: watch, netlogo

I am 'watch'-ing an agent and now want to programmatically 'unwatch' the agent (so that no agents are being watched).I am running the model using the 3D view (in NetLogo 5.0.4).  It seems from the User Manual that the only way of unwatching is to use 'reset-perspective', but this has the undesirable side effect of resetting the perspective in the 3D view.  Is there a better way of unwatching that does not disturb the view?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to call [`reset-perspective`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-perspective) in NetLogo 3D without returning the observer to its default position.

There is, however, a way to work around this: you can ask the [`subject`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#subject) currently being watched to [`hatch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#hatch) a hidden "dummy" turtle at its current position and [`watch`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#watch) this dummy instead while your original subject keeps on moving. (It's not seamless, though, because the "spotlight" circle stays around the dummy.)

Here is a full example, in which there is a `travelers` breed for the regular turtles and a `cameras` breed for the dummies:

```
breed [ travelers traveler ]
breed [ cameras camera ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-travellers 10
  watch one-of travelers
end

to go
  ask travelers [ fd 0.1 ]
end

to stop-watching
  if subject != nobody [
    ask subject [
      hatch-cameras 1 [
        set hidden? true
        watch-me
        ask other cameras [ die ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

This assumes that `stop-watching` is called from an interface button.

Answer (score 1):

Support for programmatic control of the observer in NetLogo 3D is... spotty.

You could store the values of `__oxcor`, `__oycor`, and `__ozcor` and then restore them using `setxyz` after calling `reset-perspective`.

But there's also pitch and roll.  You can read them with `__opitch` and `__oroll`, but it appears to me they are not directly settable. I imagine you could use `facexyz` to restore the pitch at least, but not the roll?  3D stuff confuses me.

Note that NetLogo's extensions API could be used to write an extension that does what you want.